# Сортировка матрицы в нужном порядке

Tags: javascript

Делаю тестовые задания перед началом курсов. Попалась такая задача:
есть матрица, причем может быть любого размера, например:

```
[
 [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6 ],
 [ 7, 8, 9 ],
]
```

Ее нужно отсортировать в такой массив:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: @entithat: тут главное - это порядок в новом массиве.

Comment: @UModeL, ага, не заметил, что там 6 5 4

Comment: @entithat: хотя... Просто каждый второй массив просто реверснуть перед конкатом...

Comment: да, в том то и дело, что нечетные подмассивы по возрастанию, а четные - по убыванию

Comment: Хорошо бы прописать в явном виде, как нужно отсортировать.

Answer (score 5):

### Towel sort algorithm

Изначально это была не совсем сортировка. Скорее, "укладка полотенцем" - т.е. когда у каждого последующего элемента матрицы порядок в массиве менялся на обратный:

```js
const arr = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ 10, 12, 11 ] ];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    return acc.concat((!(i % 2) ? cur : cur.reverse()));
  }, [])
);
```

Дальнейшее развитие предполагает дополнительную сортировку значений в самих массивах, а не просто реверс порядка элементов:

```js
const arr = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ 10, 12, 11 ] ];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    cur.sort((a, b) => !(i & 1) ? a - b : b - a).map(e => acc.push(e));
    return acc;
  }, [])
);
```

*Отличия в вариантах можно видеть на примере последнего элемента матрицы.*

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Кстати в задании написано, что это towel sort algorithm, но я сама ничего не смогла нагуглить про него. Вы слышали про такой, как он по-русски звучит?

Comment: https://github.com/rolling-scopes-school/towel-sort

Comment: Не слышал, это видимо автор этой задачи его так назвал :)

Comment: `towel sort algorithm` - обход змейкой или зигзагом, а по английски буквально - как постельное бельё или полотенце сложено в стопке

Comment: @MBo, что-то мне трудно совместить это с постельным бельём. Но буду знать :)

Comment: @entithat: Вы не против, если я ваш ответ дополню?

Comment: @UModeL, дополните

Comment: @entithat: возможно, что именно так, как у Вас нужно автору вопроса. Я дополнил, но варианты это разные, с разным результатом, так что не вижу лишней сортировки у Вас.